# Creating a glow effect via jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to create a glow effect like one is in this flash template via jQuery:

[**Flash Template**](http://images.templatemonster.com/screenshots/12700/12732.html)

i think that i must use a **jQuery plugin** for an effect that is applies to circle and text that is on top of the circle in this Template..

i Search on google and found this two but those are not that things i want :
[Animation Particles Text](http://codecanyon.net/item/animation-particles-text/1389813?ref=ubaidullahbutt)
[HTML5 Canvas Glow Effects jQuery Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/shiner-html5-canvas-glow-effects-jquery-plugin/952519?ref=ubaidullahbutt)

is there an plugin for create this effect or near it ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking about is a specific way of making something `glow`. Now glow comes hand in hand with `fade` . You gotta fade something to make it glow.

Now CSS3 can do that for you .

You have to set : `-webkit-box-shadow`, `-moz-box-shadow` and `box-shadow` like this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px red; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px green;
box-shadow:0 0 20px brown;
```

Find two implementations of the same here :

[FIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/bXY5F/7/) AND [FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/kw5Ys/235/)

Comment: FYI: The vendor prefixes haven't been necessary since Chrome 10 and Firefox 4, respectively.